# I can play a bundle-supplied .mpg/.mp4 file; but not a remote URL. Remedy?

Tags: video-streaming, swift2, avplayer

I'm trying to play a video via its URL; i.e., video streaming.

The following code works when the url is local, within the bundle:

```
class EditShowVideoViewController:AVPlayerViewController {

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleNotification",
            name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
            object: nil)

        if let url = NSURL(string: gEditMediumTuple!.medium as! String) {
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            player!.play()
        } else {
            showAlert(sender: self.parentViewController!, withTitle: "No Video", withMessage: "No video is found.", alertPurpose: .noVideo)
        }
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func handleNotification() {
        let controller = self.parentViewController as! EditContainerViewController
        controller.rollback()
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with an remote URL.  So I tried the following:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL:url)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player!.play()
```

But I always get the following:  
[image]

I'm assuming I have to wait for the .mpg to load prior to playing it.

What's the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
let url = NSURL(string: "http://urltofile")!
let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
playerVC.player = player
self.addChildViewController(playerVC)
self.view.addSubview(playerVC.view)
playerVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
player.play()
```

be careful: if you are using iOS 9 ATS might be blocking your http calls

Comment: That's essentially what I've done.  I've expanded my code snippet to show that I'm working within  an AVPlayerViewController().   But I wasn't aware about the ATS...need to study that.

Comment: I did a 'nscurl --ats-diagnostics' check on the URL.    I passed.

Comment: i tried that too and my urls were passing also but not playing in my app, i went crazy until i put this snippet in my Info.plist: http://pastebin.com/ETjMnJt1

the odd thing is that i was not getting any errors whatsover on the debug console